# How do i stop my Power BI matrix visual from filtering out columns with no data?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

A really basic requirement this. I'm probably being stupid.

I'm working on an exercise dashboard. This includes a matrix visual which tells me how many reps I have performed across different exercises for each week within a month.

As there are 4 weeks in a month, there are 4 columns and I want this to remain static. The problem is that if I don't go to the gym for a week and therefore record no data, it filters the whole column out so it's not immediately clear that there might be a two-week gap between one column and the next. (I want the gap to be VERY clear so I know how naughty I've been)

Please see the screenshot for clarity.

Example Screenshot:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Use a calendar table with all the dates and relate your data table(s) to it. Then use the date column from this calendar table in your visuals.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't resolve the issue. I already have a linked data table, the column headers are coming from a custom 'week starting' field generated within that separate table. They still get filtered out if there's no data within the week

Comment: Show us your model.